# Variable value is incremented automatically when moved to next recordset in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, variables, adodb, recordset

I am fetching values from MS-SQL database. I am assigning a value to a variable called $SeqNumCur. After processing data for this record I am storing this value in a variable called $SeqNumPrev. I am doing this to check if difference between previous value and current value is only 1. If not I have to set up an alarm. But after setting previous variable, and when moved to next record, both variables are getting changed. Hoe to stop this. Below is code and also output.

```
$NoSeqErr = 0;
$SeqNumPrev = 0;
$SeqNumCur = 0;
while (!$Rs_Data_SP1->EOF)              
// Loop through records while there is data
{

echo "<tr >";

// increment record number
$NoSeqErr = 0;
$SeqNumCur = $Rs_Data_SP1->Fields('c_PieceName');
$NoSeqErr = $SeqNumCur - $SeqNumPrev;

echo '<br> Prev:'.$SeqNumPrev;
echo '<br> Cur:'.$SeqNumCur;
echo '<br> Err:'.$NoSeqErr;


$SeqNumPrev = $SeqNumCur;


$Rs_Data_SP1->MoveNext();                    
// Move on to next data record in the set

}
```

**

### **OUTPUT**

```
Prev:0
Cur:200331098
Err:200331098 

Prev:200331099
Cur:200331099
Err:0   

Prev:200331100
Cur:200331100
Err:0   

Prev:200331101
Cur:200331101
Err:0   

Prev:200331102
Cur:200331102
Err:0   

Prev:200331103
Cur:200331103
Err:0   

Prev:200331104
Cur:200331104
Err:0   

Prev:200331105
Cur:200331105
Err:0
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved.

I used below line

$SeqNumPrev = $SeqNumCur - 0;

instead of

$SeqNumPrev = $SeqNumCur;

I dont why, perhaps somebody can explain.

Comment: $SeqNumCur is an object and thus it is not copied on assigning. See example 4 here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php